# playframework template quote/quotation rules

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

From the playframework tutorial at the front page, 
https://www.playframework.com/
the trainer leads you through a simple example, eventually importing a javascript (coffeescript) file for the dynamic generation of a list.

He writes this, inside the index.scala.html template file, so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.at("js/index.js")'></script>
```

Note, the src attribute is single quoted, and the encapsulated at method uses double-quotes as its single string argument.

This is not quite as I might expect, as I know the @routes.Assets.at method is going to be replaced by the resulting value, and I remember it being typical in many programming languages (eg., Perl) that single quotes specify a fixed/static string value. But OK, I guess seeing as we're looking at the start of an attribute of a HTML script tag, it is OK.

Perl:

```
my $name = "Fred";
print "Hello $name\n";  // prints Hello Fred (with an endline afterwards)
print 'Hello $name\n';  // prints Hello $name\n
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_Programming/Strings

Nonetheless, I don't personally like it. And I preferred to use the opposite:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at('javascripts/index.js')"></script>
```

***However***, play doesn't like this at all, with the resulting error message being:

```
"Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - unclosed character literal
    - ')' expected but something 
     found."
```

That is most unexpected, as it is allowed in HTML,
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

and also allowed, say, in Java. For example:

```
String test = "this is 'not' a test";
```

So, ***the question is***: what is the logic behind this? 
Can I find the 'rules' to this documented somewhere? 
Is it play specific, or, as it is some kind of Scala related file (index.scala.html) it is due to a querk of the Scala syntax? 
(I am just starting out to look at Scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate the two different levels here: HTML and Scala.

Scala goes through first, replacing things that start with the `@` sign (and a few other known identifiers). So lets cut out the thing that Scala reads and works with:

```
@routes.Assets.at('javascripts/index.js')
```

As you can see, the method is given a character literal as argument, but with a String contents - which is not possible in Java (and there for neither in Scala).
This is also what it tries to tell you in the error message, it found the start of a character literal and a character, but then the character literal was not terminated.

So the logic is basic Java logic. This is one of the tricky things with these compiled templates: you have to separate in your head what goes through which parser.

Following the rules of both languages involved, the following combinations are allowed:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.at("js/index.js")'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="@routes.Assets.at("js/index.js")"></script>
```

*Note that the syntax highlighting will break for the second option in a lot of editors, including the code block above*

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply. Yes OK, I understand the error message now. So now I guess I should read more in-depth into the rules of embedding the Scala code within the HTML template file; i.e., the rules for delimitation between Scala statements or blocks when one has bits of HTML floating around the file.